# Desktop not visible, doesn't show any icons in Kubuntu

Tags: linux, desktop, kubuntu

I installed kubuntu few days back. By clicking blindly I lost my desktop - I mean it is working fine but there are no icons on the desktop and there is no task bar with list of programs.

How can I reset to the initial stage when i first installed? Can anybody help me please.

Answer (score 5):

Right click on the desktop, in the settings you can select what type of desktop you want. You probably switched from folder view into just plain background image.

As for the taskbar, do you have the panel and is just the taskbar missing, or are you missing the entire panel?

Answer (score 0):

This is how to do it on Kubuntu 14.04.

1. Make sure Widgets are Unlocked. (right click on Desktop > `Unlock Widgets`)
2. Right click on the Desktop and go to `Default Desktop Settings`.
3. Under the `View` tab, under `Layout`, change it to `Folder`.
4. Click `Apply`.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

I found an [article](http://kubuntuforums.net/forums/index.php?topic=3089972.0) on the Kubuntu forums.  Basically, you need to do <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd>, type `kcontrol` then `Desktop` -> `Panels` -> `Hiding` and un-hide it

Comment: That's KDE3 post, totally irrelevant here.

Comment: Although it's not mentioned that the question is about KDE4 or even the most recent version of Kubuntu–as far as I can tell–I suppose the assumption can be made. I don't believe a downvote was really necessary though.